# Why is Launch Darkly giving this error [LDClient] Client has not finished initializing; feature store unavailable?

Tags: ruby, launchdarkly

I'm using Launch Darkly's ruby sdk as follows:

```
@client = LaunchDarkly::LDClient.new(<sdk_key>)
hash = Hash.new
@client.variation('flag_name', hash, false)
```

However, I keep getting an error stating
**[LDClient] Client has not finished initializing; feature store unavailable, returning default value**

Does anyone know why this is the case? Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at this method's documentation: https://github.com/launchdarkly/ruby-server-sdk/blob/main/lib/ldclient-rb/ldclient.rb#L150 - it seems your client wasn't able to establish a connection to the remote server...

Comment: Thank you [Konstantin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8008340/konstantin-strukov). For some reason @data_source.initalized is false. I'm trying to step through the debugger. I noticed that initialized.make_true is not being called here

https://github.com/launchdarkly/ruby-server-sdk/blob/bb9b4d166101f04256deb29fe8c048332be94d4c/lib/ldclient-rb/in_memory_store.rb#L73